# Failed to Login in cypress, while submit the form

Tags: forms, cypress

[Image of Failed Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKW0S.png)
Failed to login in form while using the submit() function of cypress. It takes the input for Email & password field but unable to submit the form for sign in.

Selector:

```
loginButton: '#new_user',
emailFieldId: '#user_email',
passwordFieldId: '#user_password'
```

,

Methods:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('enterEmail', (loc,data) => {
  cy.get(loc.emailFieldId, {timeout: 20000 }).type(data);
});

Cypress.Commands.add('enterPassword', (loc,data) => {
  cy.get(loc.passwordFieldId).type(data);
});

Cypress.Commands.add('clickLoginButton', (loc) => {
  cy.get(loc.loginButton).submit();
});
```

UseCase:

```
cy.enterEmail(LoginPage,LoginData.email);
cy.enterPassword(LoginPage,LoginData.password);
cy.loginButton(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the error message you are getting ?

Comment: @AlapanDas I have Updated the question again and added the code as well

Comment: It seems that the submit worked. Test failed at finding the element. Are you sure that the selector is correct?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, Selector is accurate, and it hit at the desired place